# Multiple ssh keys on Heroku

Tags: ssh, rsa, ssh-keys

I have:

Computer A with `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

Computer B with different `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` (it's not the same as that one from computer A) and `id_rsa2` `id_rsa2.pub`

I created an account on heroku, with `id_rsa.pub` from machine A. Now I try to pull a project on machine B, so i tried to add `id_rsa.pub` from machine B. Unfortunately, some time ago I used it in another Heroku project (with another account) and I can't use it in this one. So I added `id_rsa2.pub`, and it's valid. But `heroku git:clone` still tries to use `id_rsa` instead of `id_rsa2`. How can I force it?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to define local different domains locally in your machine, this is done by

adding the following to you ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host heroku.personal
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
Host heroku.work
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

now you can clone the project using git clone git@heroku.work:your-app-name.git
note that heroku.work is used instead of heroku.com

now we need to change .git/config in the project to cause any further git commands to use the new url

note that url in the file /path/to/your/app/.git/config  is set to the url that you used in git clone command